# ScreenX and ScreenY won't align element with cursor when browser has screen zoom

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

When a screen is zoomed, the `event.screenX` and `event.screenY` of a `MouseEvent` are not equatable to px offsets from the top and bottom.  They fall slowly behind when zoomed out, and jump slowly ahead when zoomed in.

How can I take screen zoom into account to make an element follow my cursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to not use `screenX` and `screenY`, and instead use `clientX` and `clientY`.  These measurements are zoom relative, and also viewport relative (so they will still work if your code is embedded in a viewport).